# How to drop duplicates in source data set (JSON) and load data into azure SQL DB in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a table in SQL DB with primary key fields. Now i am using a copy activity in azure data factory with source dataset(JSON).

We are writing this data into sink dataset(SQL DB) but the pipeline is failing with the below error

```
"message": "'Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Violation of 
 PRIMARY KEY constraint &apos;PK__field__399771B9251AD6D4&apos;. Cannot 
 insert duplicate key in object &apos;dbo.crop_original_new&apos;. The 
 duplicate key value is (9161&#44; en).\r\nThe statement has been 
 terminated.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=2627,Class=14,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors= 
[{Class=14,Number=2627,State=1,Message=Violation of PRIMARY KEY 
constraint &apos;PK__field__399771B9251AD6D4&apos;. Cannot insert 
duplicate key in object &apos;Table&apos;. The duplicate key value is 
(9161&#44; en).,},{Class=0,Number=3621,State=0,Message=The statement has 
been terminated.,},],'",
```

Comment: You need to write to a staging environment and then update your SQL DB from there, checking for duplicates or updates along the way.

Comment: Can you please show us some of your JSON dataset? I tried in "Copy data",  there isn't duplicates in settings.https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJiY3.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fault tolerance setting provided in copy activity to skip incompatible rows.

[Setting image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/actVX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the finest solution would be:

- Create a staging table in your SQL environment stg_table (this table should have a different key policy)
- Load data from JSON source to stg_table
- Write a stored procedure to clean data from duplicates and to load into your destination table

Or if you are familiar with Mapping Data Flows in ADF you can check [this](https://kromerbigdata.com/2019/04/21/use-adf-mapping-data-flows-for-fuzzy-matching-and-dedupe/) article by Mark Kromer

Comment: for the second option, In data flow we don’t have option to create a source for JSON file to perform dedupe. And for the first option staging, azure will charge you when you write the data into target and we have 1 bilion data to write into the target. So, we cannot design to have a staging table and drop duplicates and again load it to the desired target

Comment: yes, indeed. 
for mapping data flows you should first Copy data with Copy Activity to some of the available sources (ADLS GEN1, Azure SQL database, Blob, Azure SQL datawarehouse) and then to perform mapping flows. 
If you dont have any of these services, then option 1 is way to go.